# Power series with non-negative i.i.d. random coefficients

Tags: probability, probability-theory, power-series

I have the power series

$$\sum_n e^{X_n}x^n$$

where $X_n$ are non-negative, independent, identically distributed.
I'm supposed to find the a.s. radius of convergence in the cases (1) $E[X_n]<\infty$ and (2) $E[X_n] = \infty$.

Case (1): By Cauchy-Hadamard, we know that $r^{-1} = \limsup_n e^\frac{X_n}{n} = \exp\left(\limsup_n\frac{X_n}{n}\right)$. If we assume
$$\limsup_n \frac{X_n}{n}\ne 0 \text{ a.s.}\implies X_n \text{ not bounded a.s.}$$
which is a contradiction as the expected value is finite and $X_n \ge 0$, so we have:
$$\limsup_n \frac{X_n}{n} = 0 \text{ a.s.}\implies r^{-1} = r = 1 \text{ a.s.}$$
Is this argument correct as it stands? I feel I may have missed something, as I never used independence.

Case (2): I don't know how exactly to handle this case, as the same approach as (1) has some problems, as the radius of convergence should be $0$ as far as I can tell. Again: can we use independence somehow?

Comment: Does the three-series test work?

Comment: @Masacroso how do you apply Borel-Cantelli when we aren't measuring sets?

Comment: Do you mean $X^n$ or is the lowercase $x$ denoting a real (i.e. nonstochastic) variable?

Comment: @Math1000 the lowercase x denotes the real variable of the power series (for the radius of convergence)

Answer (score -1):

You used independence implicitly when you deduced that if $Y:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}X_n/n>0$ a.s. then $\operatorname{E}[X_1]=\infty $. For this assertion independence is required, just note that $\{X_n/n>0\text{ i.o. }\}=\{X_n>0\text{ i.o. }\}$, so setting $X_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R},
\, x\mapsto 1$ for all $n$, where the probability measure is the Lebesgue measure, then we have that $\operatorname{P} [X_n/n>0]=1$ for all $n$, so $\operatorname{P} [X_n/n>0\text{ i.o. }]=1$, however $\operatorname{E}[X_n]=1<\infty $.

But if the $X_n$ are independent then $Y$ is a tail function, so $Y$ is constant a.s. Thus asserting that $\operatorname{P} [Y>0]=1$, when independence is in play, is asserting that $Y=k$ for some $k\in(0,\infty ]$, and from here we can deduce that $\operatorname{E}[X_n]=\infty $ using the first Borel-Cantelli lemma and a formula for the expectation when the r.v. are non-negative (see below).

A way to show the result is noticing that as the $X_n$ are non-negative, then $\mathrm{E}[X_1]=\int_{[0,\infty )}\Pr [X_1\geqslant t]\mathop{}\!d t$, and so for any chosen $\epsilon >0$ we have that
$$
\begin{align*}
\epsilon \Pr [X_1\geqslant (n+1) \epsilon ]\leqslant \int_{n \epsilon }^{(n+1) \epsilon }\Pr [X_1\geqslant t] \mathop{}\!dt \leqslant \epsilon \Pr [X_1\geqslant n \epsilon ]\\
 \therefore\quad \epsilon\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\Pr [X_1\geqslant (n+1)\epsilon ]\leqslant \mathrm{E}[X_1]\leqslant \epsilon \sum_{n\geqslant 0}\Pr [X_1\geqslant n \epsilon ]
\end{align*}\tag1
$$
and
$$
\Pr [e^{X_k}\geqslant c^{-k} \text{ i.o. }]=\Pr [X_k\geqslant k\log(c^{-1})\text{ i.o. }]\tag2
$$
So we can use (1) and (2) and the Borel-Cantelli lemmas to reach the result, that is: if $\operatorname{E}[X_1]<\infty $ then the radius of convergence is one, and if the expectation diverges to infinity then it is zero.